# MySQL Procedures behaving weird once variables are inserted

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm having a frustrating time with MySQL and a procedure I'm writing and wanted to see if anyone else had any clues as to what is going on.

The procedure I have below will dynamically transpose rows in a table to columns. It is working perfectly except for the very last `WHERE` statement.

If I have either of the following `WHERE` statements it works fine.

```
WHERE t.company_id = v_company_id AND t.class = 'asset_property'

WHERE t.company_id IN (v_company_id) AND t.class = 'asset_property'
```

However, if I also want to grab records where the company_id could be 1 OR whatever value is passed in, it refuses to run. The only change made to the query is to the 'WHERE` statement. None of these versions will work.

```
WHERE (t.company_id = v_company_id OR t.company_id = 1) AND t.class = 'asset_property'

WHERE t.company_id IN (v_company_id, 1) AND t.class = 'asset_property'

WHERE t.company_id IN (161, 1) AND t.class = 'asset_property'
```

Appreciate any assistance that someone more versed in MySQL can provide. I've tried debugging as best I can and the only error I can seem to find is that when I try to get `t.company_id` to be one of two values, there is a generic error saying `Invalid table name`.

The full procedure is below.

**(See Update 1)**

Finally, if I generate the working statement above, then manually add in the lines for `t.company_id = 1` records, it works perfectly and creates the following query.

**(See Update 1)**

---

### Update 1

So that others can simulate what I'm seeing, I've built a test DB with test data in it so you can try this yourself. Also removing some of the code above to save space...

Trying to add this here blew out my character limit. I've uploaded it to my personal site. (Please let me know if this is not a safe thing to do!)
[Test DB](http://jordanmillar.com/debug/Test_DB.txt)

Once you've created this DB, here are some procedures and SQL statements that you can run to test it and simulate what I'm doing.

The Procedure `fill_tableau_ap` that is in the Test DB will run and will create a table with the data in it (but is missing the company 1 records).

That Procedure generates the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE dw_161.tableau_ap AS 
    SELECT a.id as "Asset ID (ap)", 
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2473 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Business Class" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2294 then ap.date_value else null end) as "COI Date" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2293 then ap.date_value else null end) as "Compliance Date" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2291 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Fuel Type" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2292 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Operator" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2296 then ap.numeric_value else null end) as "PAX Capacity" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2295 then ap.date_value else null end) as "Registration Expiry" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2290 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Taxi Plate" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2323 then ap.text_value else null end) as "VIN" 
    FROM dw_161.equipment AS a 
    JOIN dw_161.asset_properties ap ON ap.asset_id = a.id 
    JOIN dw_161.sites AS s on a.site_id = s.id 
    WHERE dw_161.s.company_id = 161 
    GROUP BY a.id;
```

If I manually, add in a single item from company 1 into that above statement as below, I can run this on the DB and it also works. Here's what it looks like in case you also want to run it on the Test DB.

```
CREATE TABLE dw_161.tableau_ap AS 
    SELECT a.id as "Asset ID (ap)", 
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2473 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Business Class" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2294 then ap.date_value else null end) as "COI Date" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2293 then ap.date_value else null end) as "Compliance Date" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2291 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Fuel Type" ,
## Next field added manually from company 1 into the query
        max(case when ap.property_id = 213 then ap.numeric_value else null end) as "Odometer" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2292 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Operator" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2296 then ap.numeric_value else null end) as "PAX Capacity" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2295 then ap.date_value else null end) as "Registration Expiry" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2290 then ap.text_value else null end) as "Taxi Plate" ,
        max(case when ap.property_id = 2323 then ap.text_value else null end) as "VIN" 
    FROM dw_161.equipment AS a 
    JOIN dw_161.asset_properties ap ON ap.asset_id = a.id 
    JOIN dw_161.sites AS s on a.site_id = s.id 
    WHERE dw_161.s.company_id = 161 
    GROUP BY a.id;
```

So we can conclude, that if I can get the statement generated correctly, it will run and work. So it must be a problem with the statement generation.

Breaking the procedure into parts, there is the second half that feeds the list of Asset Properties into the first half. That's where I think things are going haywire. Specifically, in this section of the Procedure:

```
    SELECT i.id as ap_id, item as ap_name, asset_property_data_type as ap_data_type
    FROM dw_161.config_items as i
    JOIN dw_161.config_tables as t on t.id = i.table_id
    WHERE t.company_id IN (v_company_id) AND t.class = 'asset_property'    
    ORDER BY ap_name
```

So what happens if I pull out the variable `v_company_id` and manually enter what I am ultimately look for and run this, as follows? Well naturally it works and provides a list of all the asset properties. (*there are no duplicates here.*)

```
SELECT i.id as ap_id, item as ap_name, asset_property_data_type as ap_data_type
FROM dw_161.config_items as i
JOIN dw_161.config_tables as t on t.id = i.table_id
WHERE t.company_id IN (161,1) AND t.class = 'asset_property'    
ORDER BY ap_name
```

---

### Update 2

ARGH!!! Whilst going through all of this and making sure that it was completely repeatable for others looking at it, I noticed one of the fields was registered as `decimal` in the DB when we store both numeric and decimal data in a single field called `numeric_value` in the table. That ulitimately was my problem and I appeared to have [Rubber Ducked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) myself. Changing the procedure to translate any fields stored in the DB to the actual column names solved my problem!

Here is the finished procedure in case anyone is interested. It's an interesting bit of code for transposing rows into columns in a DB if others need that.

```
BEGIN

    SET  @sql = concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dw_', v_company_id, '.tableau_ap;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    SET @sql = (select concat('CREATE TABLE dw_', v_company_id, '.tableau_ap AS SELECT a.id as "Asset ID (ap)", ',
            group_concat(
                concat('max(case when ap.property_id = ',ap_id, ' then ap.', ap_data_type, '_value else null end) as "', ap_name,'" ')
            ),
            'FROM dw_', v_company_id, '.equipment AS a ',
            'JOIN dw_', v_company_id, '.asset_properties ap ON ap.asset_id = a.id ',
            'JOIN dw_', v_company_id, '.sites AS s on a.site_id = s.id ',
            'WHERE dw_', v_company_id, '.s.company_id = ', v_company_id,' ',
            'GROUP BY a.id;'
            )
    from 
    (
        SELECT i.id as ap_id, item as ap_name, 
            (CASE asset_property_data_type
                WHEN 'numeric' THEN 'numeric'
                WHEN 'decimal' THEN 'numeric'
                WHEN 'calculated' THEN 'numeric'
                WHEN 'text' THEN 'text'
                WHEN 'date' THEN 'date'
                WHEN 'asset' THEN 'id'
                WHEN 'employee' THEN 'id'
                WHEN 'bar-code' THEN 'text'
                WHEN 'currency' THEN 'numeric'
                WHEN 'time' THEN 'date'
                WHEN 'duration' THEN 'date'
                WHEN 'serial' THEN 'text'
             END) AS ap_data_type
        FROM dw_161.config_items as i
        JOIN dw_161.config_tables as t on t.id = i.table_id
        WHERE t.company_id IN (v_company_id,1) AND t.class = 'asset_property'    
        ORDER BY ap_name) a
    )
    ;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: is there any error when you execute the stored procedure?

Comment: Not that I can see. It just says it finishes but there is no file created. Not sure where I can find out if there are errors.

Comment: Can you add the @sql that will be generated by your 2-company version, as well as the modified, working @sql where you manually added the  `t.company_id = 1`? Debugging your code without data, error message and something more conrete than "not working" is a lot harder than it has to be with that additional information. My first guess would be that the ap-names might not be unique anymore (so your code generate several columns with e.g. the name "Asset Tag" because both companies 1 and 161 have such an asset). On the other hand, the error message should be different then.

Comment: 'when I try to get t.company_id to be one of two values' should you not be filtering out the one you don't want in  'SELECT i.id ...FROM chekrite_prod.config_items as i'?

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare. As I was going through building out a Test DB for others I ended up solving it myself. Another +1 for the Rubber Duck Debugging method!

Answer (score 0):

See **Update 2** above in the original post.